# MATLAB calls function every time I compile the file

Tags: matlab

I am fairly new to MATLAB, and I wrote the following function to rotate a vector by 90 degrees anticlockwise.

```
function w = rotate(v)
R=[0,-1;1,0];
w=R*v;
end
```

but every time I compile the file, MATLAB calls rotate with an argument v which I have not defined yet, which leads to an error. How do I stop MATLAB from calling this function when I compile the file? I have tried to fiddle with the Run icon but the most I was able to do was to give a different input to rotate every time I compiled the file. (I'm using MATLAB R2020a)

Comment: MATLAB is an interpreted language. Why are you trying to compile the file?

Comment: What do you do when you “compile the file”? There is the MATLAB Compiler, which creates a standalone program from your code. It should not run the code. Other than that there is no “compiling” in MATLAB.

Comment: You don't tell MATLAB when to compile. You just always call the function as if it's already compiled.

Comment: Are you trying to just execute this function (clicking the run icon on a file containing only this function)?  That won't work, functions are not directly executable in Matlab and need to be called with the proper arguments.

Comment: Right, I didn't know that I don't have to click the Run icon every time I edit my function. Thanks for the help.